# In .htaccess of how to redirect urls after removing a word as a new structure applied

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a WordPress site and recently i have changed the URLs structure and that cause a lot of NOT found errors as i found at google WebMaster tools
the old URL looks like that

> http://www.akhbaralan.com/date/2014/01/page/76/

and i want it to look like that

> http://www.akhbaralan.com/2014/01/page/76/

removing the word and redirect the URL to the one without the word

**date**

after the domain name
i searched a lot here in Stack Overflow and googled for it
but nothing have worked
i tried the the follwing

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^date/(.*)$ http://www.akhbaralan.com//$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^date/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^date/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/date/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^date/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

here is the full .htaccess  file code and i have placed it at the home directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# edirect cateories 3/4/2014
redirect 301 /cat8 /?cat=8
redirect 301 /cat3 /?cat=3
redirect 301 /cat2 /?cat=2
redirect 301 /cat4 /?cat=4
redirect 301 /cat5 /?cat=5
redirect 301 /cat7 /?cat=7
# nor found http://www.akhbaralan.com/date/2014/01/page/76/
# 7/7/2014
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^date/(.*)$ http://www.akhbaralan.com//$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you post your existing rules from your .htaccess?

Comment: Where did you put these rules (where in the htaccess file and where is the htaccess file)?

Comment: thank you anubhava i have posted the existing rules from my.htaccess @JonLin Lin the file placed at the home dirctory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Keep your 301 rules before WP default rules
2. Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` ones

Your revised .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^date/(.*)$ http://www.akhbaralan.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^cat([0-9]+)/?$ /?cat=$1 [L,QSA,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you,  your code works great and you have also fixed such redirect 301 /cat7 /?cat=7 rules as well